# Problems with Ruby one? and include? methods

Tags: ruby

MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) in order to reproduce the same problem as mine:

at rspec file place:

```
RSpec.describe 'Predicate Enumerable Exercises' do

  describe 'coffee drink exercise' do
    it 'returns true when espresso is included' do
      drink_list = ["milk", "juice", "espresso"]
      expect(coffee_drink?(drink_list)).to be true
    end
  end

  describe 'valid scores exercise' do
    it 'returns true when only one score is a 10' do
      score_list = { easy_to_read: 10, uses_best_practices: 8, clever: 7 }
      perfect_score = 10
      expect(valid_scores?(score_list, perfect_score)).to be true
    end 
  end

end
```

at the actual functions file:

```
def coffee_drink?(drink_list)
  drink_list.include?("coffee" || "espresso")
end

def valid_scores?(score_list, perfect_score)
  score_list.one?{|score| score == perfect_score}
end
```

I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong in my code because I am relying on built-in methods (one?, include?) so I'm not sure what is the actual problem

I created 2 methods, `coffee_drink?(drink_list)` and `valid_scores?(score_list, perfect_score)`.

`coffee_drink?` gets an array, which then returns true only if it includes either the word `coffee` or `espresso`.
I used the following to return the expected: `drink_list.include?("coffee" || "espresso")`
But when I have `espresso` on my list and no `coffee` the console returns:

> returns true when espresso is included (FAILED - 1)

Where `drink_list` is `["milk", "juice", "espresso"]`

For `valid_scores?` it gets an array and integer, and returns true when only one value in the array is equal to that integer. But I expected that `score_list.one?{|score| score == perfect_score}` would return true when only one value is true. Instead I get:

> returns true when only one score is a 10 (FAILED - 2)

Where the array is

```
score_list = { easy_to_read: 10, uses_best_practices: 8, clever: 7 }
```

and the integer is

```
perfect_score = 10
```

I am using ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux] if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `include?` code behaves different than expected because:

```
"coffee" || "espresso" #=> "coffee"

# so
drink_list.include?("coffee" || "espresso")
# evaluates to
drink_list.include?("coffee")
```

You'll have to either use 2 separate `include?` calls, or some other option like [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) or [`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-26).

```
drink_list.include?("coffee") || drink_list.include?("espresso")
# or
drink_list.any? { |drink| drink == "coffee" || drink == "espresso" }
drink_list.any?(/\A(coffee|espresso)\z/)
(drink_list & ["coffee", "espresso"]).size.positive? # !(...).empty? also works
```

---

Your `one?` code behaves different than expected because `score_list` is not an array, but a hash (dictionary/map in other languages). A hash consists of key/value pairs which are passed as array (`[key, value]`) to the `one?` block.

```
score_list.one? { |pair| pair.last == perfect_score }
```

Alternatively you can use [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
score_list.one? { |key, value| value == perfect_score }
```

Or retrieve only the [`values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-values) beforehand:

```
score_list.values.one? { |score| score == perfect_score  }
```

Comment: You can also use `(drink_list & ["coffee", "espresso"]).any?`

Answer (score 0):

If you think this looks familiar, it's from The Odin Project's Ruby course, Predicate Enumerable Methods section and the exercise is from the predicate_enumerable_exercises.rb.

For the first one I used an if, else statement like:

```rb
if drink_list.include?('coffee') || drink_list.include?('espresso')
  true
else
  false
end
```

And for the last one, you can pass an argument to `one?`. I did it like this:

```rb
score_list.values.one?(perfect_score)
```

Also, you said array, I think you meant hash, score_list is a hash.